# jQuery doesn't effect as script but in console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add a clickon action on the first show more link on my [webpage](https://www.countrycorn.com.au/charity-and-donations/). If I try this code in the console:

```
jQuery("#wpc_59c09c751543d > div > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > p")
    .attr("onclick", "document.getElementById('showExpandImage').style.display = 'block'");
```

It this is working. If you try it by yourself in the console you see, that the image will popup if you hit show more. But if I insert it as a script in the footer, you can find the code at the end of the source code of the page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#wpc_59c09c751543d > div > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > p")
            .attr("onclick", "document.getElementById('showExpandImage').style.display = 'block'");
    });
</script>
```

It just doesn't add the onclick event... why is that and how can I fix that?
It gets definitly loaded. I tried that with an `alert()` event. But I removed the `alert()` event because of the visitors. Would be glad about help.

Comment: That selector though... :)

Comment: `attr("onclick",`  your setting the click handler on the attribute, your DOM has already rendered.  Change to using jQuery's click event.

Comment: That selector and javascript-in-a-string makes me weep tears of joy at how far humanity has come

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#wpc_59c09c751543d > div > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > p").click( function(){
    $('#showExpandImage').css('display', 'block');
});
```

You can use the jQuery function `click()` without need to call the function when the doc is ready

[jQuery click function](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem several times.

The problem is that your element loads after script loads, the reason for this can be:

1. your element is dynamically loaded through java script

Solution to this problem is to load script when element is done loading.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested in on your web-site, and this should work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
       jQuery("#wpc_59c09c751543d > div > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > p").click(function() 
       {
           jQuery("#showExpandImage").css("display", "block");         
       });
});
```

**EDIT:**
I would also suggest that you add an ID to your element and change the long selector to use the id. For example you can add an id of `my-link` and change it to:

```
$("#my-link").click(....)
```